# Using Counter in python for Fibonacci

Tags: python, recursion, counter, fibonacci

I've written a program that essentially does Fibonacci by reading from a dictionary that it creates (given {0:0, 1:1} to start). Obviously if it doesn't have it in the dictionary, it will create until it does, and then later calls so it doesn't have to do the same sequence over and over again. What I'm having difficulty with is using the Counter object to keep track of the instructions done by the algorithm (so I can afterwards plot the graph of how many calls as the initial n increases). Never used class Counter before or memoization so I'm a bit lost here at the end.

```
    dic = {0:0, 1:1}

    def main():
        n = int(input("Number to Fibonacci?"))
        fib(n)
        print(dic[n])
        Counter()
        memoization(n, Counter, dic)

    def fib(n):
        if n in dic:
            return dic[n]
        else:
            if n < 2:
                dic[n] = n
            else:
                dic[n] = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
                return dic[n]

    class Counter():
        def __init__(self):
            self._number = 0
        def increment(self):
            self._number += 1
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self._number)
        def print():
            print(str(self._number))

    def memoization(n, Counter, dic):
        if n in dic:
            return dic[n]
        else:
            c.increment()

     main()
```

this is what I have but I honestly don't know where to go from here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand really where you got this `Counter` class or why you're trying to do this.  Right now it doesn't represent anything but an integer that you're incrementing.  Much of this code is just broken.  You might consider reading up more on how to do memoization in Python instead of getting hung up on doing anything with this useless `Counter` class.  If you search SO there are already many answers to how to write fibonacci in Python, including memoized versions.  Though this sounds like homework to me so I don't really know what to tell you...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell your `Counter` simply needs to be declared properly.  This ensures that you pass the same instance of the `Counter` class along to the method.

```
def main():
    ...
    my_counter_name = Counter() # <-- NAME THIS
    memoization(n, my_counter_name, dic) # <-- pass the same name
```

And change this:

```
def memoization(n, Counter, dic): # <-- No need to write the class in Python
                                  #     just the local name for the variable
        if n in dic:
            return dic[n]
        else:
            c.increment()
```

If you would like to use c as the name for the counter as you have indicated in line 4 of the `memoization` method, you should change the input variable to this:

```
def memoization(n, c, dic):
        if n in dic:
            return dic[n]
        else:
            c.increment()
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: That fixes the basic code, but the `Counter` instances still plays absolutely no role in the memoization implementation. I'm not even sure what you would use it for in implementing `fib`.

Comment: There are a few more flaws I can see in this implementation of what I believe their end goal to be.  The asker mentions using a  `Counter` to keep track of the calls made 'memoization' method.  I figured knowing the things I pointed out would at least allow for the asker to have the simpler corrected syntax issues to debug the algorithmic problems with the code.

Comment: I see what you're saying, that makes sense.  Hopefully it will put them on the right track at least.